# How to change the compile path for a PHP project in eclipse (mac version)

Tags: php, eclipse, compilation, localhost

I use XAMPP server in mac and I'm trying to compile a PHP project to /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/ so the url is correct when running the project in a browser under localhost, but i can't find where to specify additional compile (or just copy) paths and i'm wondering if it's even possible.

Other option could be pointing the url to the compile path, but i can't make it work either.

Comment: Well, I ended up creating the workspace directly in the /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/, but that's not an elegant solution because i'm used to have my workspaces on a external drive to be able to work with them in any computer.